# Right Parenthesis error 'INT(8)' in SQLPLUS

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I'm trying to rectify this error

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Reservation_21BAI1750(

  2  PNR number(9),

  3  Journey_Date Date NULL,

  4  No_of_Seats INT(8) ZEROFILL CHECK (No_of_Seats < 50),

  5  Address varchar2(50) NULL,

  6  Contact_No number(9) UNIQUE,

  7  BusNo varchar2(10),

  8  Seat_No number NOT NULL

  9  );
```

Error message received:

> No_of_Seats INT(8) ZEROFILL CHECK (No_of_Seats < 50),
> *
> ERROR at line 4:
> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I get the exact same error if I don't use ZEROFILL.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: Why the tag spam with a bunch of different databases when it looks like you're using Oracle?

Comment: Sqlplus is an sql client for oracle. This error message comes from oracle, nit from sqlplus. There is no indication that the question has anything to do with sqlplus. You would get the same syntax error from any oracle sql cluent.

Comment: @RF1991 I'm using SQLPlus connected to oracle database 21c.

Answer (score 0):

There's no ZEROFILL in Oracle, while INT datatype doesn't have size. Also, you don't have to specify NULLs for columns that accept them; that's default.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE reservation_21bai1750
  2  (
  3     pnr            NUMBER (9),
  4     journey_date   DATE,
  5     no_of_seats    INT CHECK (no_of_seats < 50),
  6     address        VARCHAR2 (50),
  7     contact_no     NUMBER (9) UNIQUE,
  8     busno          VARCHAR2 (10),
  9     seat_no        NUMBER NOT NULL
 10  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `zerofill` you can use `LPAD` when data is read:

```
CREATE TABLE Reservation_21BAI1750(

PNR number(9),

 Journey_Date Date NULL,

 No_of_Seats number(8),

 Address varchar2(50) NULL,

 Contact_No number(9) UNIQUE,

 BusNo varchar2(10),

 Seat_No number NOT NULL,
  
 CONSTRAINT CH_Reservation_No_of_Seats CHECK  (No_of_Seats < 50) 

 );
```

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Reservation_21BAI1750 (PNR, Journey_Date, No_of_Seats, Address, Contact_No, BusNo, Seat_No)
VALUES (1, TO_DATE('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 15, '123 Main St', 10001, 'A100', 1);


INSERT INTO Reservation_21BAI1750 (PNR, Journey_Date, No_of_Seats, Address, Contact_No, BusNo, Seat_No)
VALUES (2, TO_DATE('2022-01-03','YYYY-MM-DD'), 25, '789 Elm St', 10002, 'C300', 3);

SELECT LPAD(No_of_Seats, 8, '0') AS Padded_Seat_No 
FROM Reservation_21BAI1750;
```

and here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c66de4/15).